# $G/[G,G]$, irreps and conjugacy classes

Tags: rt.representation-theory

This question is motivated by [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102879/bijection-between-irreducible-representations-and-conjugacy-classes-of-finite-gro). Basically, the remark of Bugs Bunny in comments made me think - OK, there is an ambiguity in choosing between a Young diagram and its transpose when constructing irreps of $S_n$, but it is somewhat remarkable: it corresponds in terms of irreps to tensoring representations with the sign representation. There is also of course the remark of Gjergji Zaimi suggesting that for abelian groups the ambiguity is maximal possible, since we are literally dealing with a group vs its dual. This of course makes one wonder if the group of characters $G/[G,G]$ is somehow responsible for the key ambiguities, hence this (possibly very naive) question.

Of course the dual group of $G/[G,G]$ acts on irreps of $G$: that dual group is just the group of one-dimensional irreps of $G$, and we can tensor irreps of $G$ with those. I thought I had a way to make $G/[G,G]$ act in a very easy way on conjugacy classes of $G$, but David Speyer drew my attention to the fact that it must be much less obvious. Hence for the moment my question is - is there a way to repair the original question along these lines? For instance, is there an action of $G/[G,G]$ on conjugacy classes of $G$ for which there is a natural (in some sense) bijection between the orbits of $G/[G,G]\simeq (G/[G,G])^\vee$ on the conjugacy classes of $G$ and the irreps of $G$?

Comment: I'm confused. How does $G/[G,G]$ act on conjugacy classes? For example , if $G$ is $S_n$, how does the nontrivial element of $S_n/[S_n, S_n]$ act on the identity?

Comment: I know you want the answer to be "it takes it to the class of the $n$-cycle", but I don't understand how you get that from abstract group theory.

Comment: @David: yes you are right. There seems to be a problem. I shall for the moment formulate a less specific version of my question, and think of how to repair it. 

Comment: The group to me that most obviously acts on conjugacy classes is $\text{Out}(G)$, and previous discussion on MO (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21606/orbit-structures-of-conjugacy-class-set-and-irreducible-representation-set-under) already shows that actions of $\text{Out}(G)$ on conjugacy classes and irreps are different in general. 

Comment: I also disagree that $G/[G, G]$ is responsible for the ambiguities. Can you write down a natural bijection from the conjugacy classes of the binary icosahedral group $\tilde{A_5}$ (which is perfect) to its irreps? 

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: yes I am aware of that discussion, but somehow my question is different. I am not saying I have a clear reason to think that $G/[G,G]$ acts naturally on conjugacy classes, but I have a flicker of hope..

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: as for $A_5$, it is natural to me to assign to the 5-cycle $(12345)$ the representation for which the character of the corresponding element is $2\cos(\pm 2\pi/5)$ since in the geometric representation of the pentagon the corresponding cycle does rotate through $\pm2\pi/5$. ;-) I know more imagination is required further, I am just saying that there is no need to discard this idea right away. 

Comment: (in the previous comment $2\cos(\pm2\pi/5)$ must be $1+2\cos(\pm2\pi/5)$, of course)

Comment: One might be able to make Qiaochu's argument damning if the associated representations of the outer automorphism group of $A_5$ were the same. Unfortunately since that is just $\mathbb Z/2$ this won't happen, but are there other perfect groups with larger/less commutative outer automorphism groups?

Comment: On the positive side, an $n$-dimensional representation up to multiplication by $1$-dimensional representations gives a map $G \to PGL_n(\mathbb C)$. Given a conjugacy class of $G$, how would one produce a map $G \to PGL_n(\mathbb C)$?

Comment: @Will: up to multiplication by scalars, not up to multiplication by a $1$-dimensional representation. For example ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ has a faithful $2$-dimensional complex representation, but no non-trivial one-dimensional representation. However ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ is not isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm PGL}(2,\mathbb{C}).$

Comment: I did not claim that the determination of a homomorphism to $PGL_n(C)$ was unique, nor that, if the original map was faithful, the second map would be as well.

Comment: @Will: My problem was what you meant by ``up to multiplication by a $1$-dimensional representation." If you meant that there is one map for each $G/[G,G]$-orbit (strictly the dual group), acting by multiplication of irreducible characters, then it's clear to me.



Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Volodya You write: "@Qiaochu Yuan: yes I am aware of that discussion, " what is "that discussion" ? 

Comment: @Alexander: Qiaochu in one of his comments refers to "a previous MO discussion", what exactly is not clear?

Comment: @Volodya Is it "Bijection between irrep..." ? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/102879/bijection-between-irreducible-representations-and-conjugacy-classes-of-finite-gro (but \tiled A_5 is not discussed there) or some other ? Can you give a link ? 